# How to get php 5.6 to connect to SQL Server 2008R2 without MSVCP110.dll error

Tags: sql-server-2008, php-5.6

I installed the most recent XAMPP (xampp-win32-5.6.8-0-VC11) which has PHP 5.6.8 and I'm trying to connect it to my SQL Server 2008 R2 so I went to download the drivers from Microsoft
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

I installed the drivers, edited my php.ini to add

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

and restarted Apache to get the following error:
"The program can't start because MSVCP110.dll is missing from your computer.  Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

Am I missing something?  Do I have to install something else?

Comment: I uninstalled all of the
Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio...
that were in the system and went to
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30679
to install the latest (had to do x86) and I got past the MSVCP110.dll error and it shows SQLSRV in phpinfo.
Now when I go to my php page that connects to my server I'm getting another error "Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server."

help?

Comment: Help?  Does anyone know how to get past "This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server." error?

Comment: Did you have any luck? I were able to do it with wamp and sql server 2012